# How to evaluate $\int_0^\infty x^s\eta(x)dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

This question arise from a sub point from [How did the cutoff regulization expanded to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n=-\frac{1}{12}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262106/how-did-the-cutoff-regulization-expanded-to-sum-n-1-infty-n-frac112#comment8872634_4262354) , or the Eq. 15 in [the reference](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/).

Mainly, for the case of $s=1$, the expression
$$C_{\eta,s}=\int_0^\infty x^s\eta(x)dx$$
, where $\eta(x)\in C^k$ was a cutoff function that's $\eta(0)=1$ and $\eta(1)=0$, ought to be $$C_{\eta,1}\approx \frac{1}{2}$$

The cutoff function tried was
$$\eta_N(x)=\sqrt{1-x^N}\approx1-\frac{1}{2} x^N$$
which,
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 dx \eta_N(x)=\frac{1}{2}$$

However, it was not clear why $$\int_0^\infty x^1\eta(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}$$ without taking some kind of limit.

How to evaluate $\int_0^\infty x^s\eta(x)dx$?

Comment: There is no general answer for the integral in closed form unless you define η(x).

Comment: @TymaGaidash but was the definition correct?